# Responsive tables only working on Firefox

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm  working on a responsive layout that needs to be compatible with adobe contribute. In order to make it compatible I must use tables so I'm applying css to the tables and using media queries and float:left. Moreover, I must match the height of the containers when they are side by side, but go back to auto height once these containers are view on a smaller screen and stack vertically. (I'm doing this with pure CSS)

I accomplished to create just what I need if the site is to be viewed on Firefox:
Here is the link:  http://as.sjsu.edu/ascdc/responsive_home.htm

However, Chrome only displays the containers one below each other so there must be something I'm overseeing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%; 
    border-spacing: 10px; /*must be px*/
}
.container table {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.container {
    display: block;
    border-spacing: none;
}
.container table {
    width: 96%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2%;
}
}
```

Comment: not sure why this works in firefox, but quick view in devtools in chrome, and your containers are set to display:table...so they're never going to line up next to each other. i see your float, but thats only applied to the containers child, as well as only for smaller screens

Comment: I am using display: table; to be able to match the height when containers are next to each other.

Comment: display: table works as intended in chrome. http://as.sjsu.edu/ascdc/responsive_home.htm Please undo vote down.

Comment: BTW, its generally better if you design your layout starting with mobile and placing styles relevant to wider devices behind media queries.  If you do the reverse (like you're doing now), you're writing styles that have to be undone.  Also, your markup is pretty terrible.  http://tinker.io/7a230

Comment: @cimmanon BTW its generally better if your commentary is kept on the subject, as opposed to whatever you want to talk about. Also, your leadership is pretty terrible. With a score like yours there certainly is no excuse, especially in regards to new users. Not.cool.at.all.

Comment: @irm i didn't downvote this...what was the fix?

Comment: @cimmanon. Thank you for your input. I will fallow your advice and improve my markup. I do need to keep the tables thought. My layout needs to be compatible with an older version of Adobe Contribute so other departments can edit content.

Comment: @albert I thought you downvote since I got your comment right after. Sorry about that, and thanks for the help. Still, do you think I don't have a reasonable question? I'm new to this community and I don't see a problem with my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I wrap the tables in a div and apply the css to the divs instead, and the layout is now working on Chrome.